# Android Development Dockerfile: Why Does Android SDK Manager Hang?

Tags: android, cordova, docker, dockerfile

Building a Docker image to do Cordova development and build to Android.

The following Dockerfile gets everything set up, but running anything with the /android-sdk-linux/android command causes the whole Container to freeze up with no error message...  and that's even with --no-ui!

Similarly when I try to build ( `cordova build android` ) it hang infinitely on `Running command: /hello/platforms/android/cordova/build`

```
FROM ubuntu:trusty
MAINTAINER Antman Jones
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN echo 'debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive' | debconf-set-selections
RUN sudo apt-get -y install curl
RUN sudo apt-get -y install software-properties-common

# Cordova is an NPM package 
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN sudo npm install npm -g

# Install Java
RUN sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
RUN sudo apt-get -y update
RUN sudo apt-get -y install libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386 zlib1g:i386
RUN sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java
RUN sudo apt-get -y update
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | sudo debconf-set-selections
RUN echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | sudo debconf-set-selections
RUN sudo apt-get -y install oracle-java6-installer
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle

# Install the Android SDK
RUN wget http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
RUN tar -xvf android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz
ENV ANDROID_HOME /android-sdk-linux
ENV PATH $PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
WORKDIR /android-sdk-linux/tools
RUN ./android udpate sdk --no-ui

# Install Cordova
RUN npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same issue and it looks like the android script was hanging anytime it invoked archquery.jar. We fixed this by replacing all lines where it asks archquery.jar for the current architecture with "x86_64".

Comment: Wow, any idea why this is happening? For the record I just did `swtpath="x86_64"` and commented the whole conditional part looking for `swtpath`!